# Graph Explorer - Get joined teams, post message to a channel etc always return Error 404,405

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[image]I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API's for sending messages to a team channel ( created a trial team account with my personal mail id)  however  I am getting errors for most the API calls.

Graph Explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

GET - my profile - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
works

GET - my joined teams - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams
fails with error 404
{
"error": {
"code": "ResourceNotFound",
"message": "Resource not found.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-12-06T10:37:20",
"request-id": "47590681-8fbd-4912-8bcd-c28fc982feb8",
"client-request-id": "f75c0df3-a3bc-c542-cd10-8f275bbdb685"
} } }

POST  - send message to a channel - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/28be7684-0d3b-43cc-b709-eec08176554a/channels/19:76c3a65b63544382ba31ab5baa47521c@thread.tacv2/messages
Body
{
"body": {
"content": "Hello world"
}
}

Fails with error 405

I am not sure if it is because of my teams account ( selection option organization while set up ). I have done Modify permission -> Consent but some of them don't change to status consented.

Regards,
Sayantan

Comment: I tried the same at my tenant, but i failed to repro the issue or errors that you're getting. Make sure you provide the right consent so that you can make the API calls - its needed. HTTP 405 tells that the HTTP method in the request is not allowed on the resource.

Comment: Do you have any updates on the above?